# Identifying the suject of a conversation using spark MLlib

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to find the subject of a conversation from a predefined set of SUBJECTS being stored in a file.

Would like to know if it is possible using the SPARK or MLLIB?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at MLlib which supports multinomial naive Bayes, typically used for document classification:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html

Here more details on how it is implemented:
http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/html/htmledition/naive-bayes-text-classification-1.html

To train the model you will have to prepare some training data, basically a file with the class (the subject) and the frequency of the terms relevant to your classification.